# Unable to handle Google Authentication pop up window in robot framework test case

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am having a problem on handling google authentication pop up window in robot framework.

The process I want to automate is -

1. When a button( Sign in with google) is clicked , google authentication pop up window appears
2. Then I have to enter my username and password
3. Then  click sign up button

While running the robot framework test script , everything working fine upto clicking the 'Sign in button', but after that am not able to view the Google-authentication window in browser !

I found some similar questions around here , but those solutions didn't work for me.

Here is my test script -

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Test Setup  Open Browser  http://xyz.com  firefox
Test Teardown  Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
   Open xyz and verify login

*** Keywords ***
Open xyz and verify login
  Maximize Browser Window
  Click Element  id=my-signin2 #To click 'Sign in with google' link in main page
  Select WIndow  title=Sign in - Google Accounts #To select the new pop up window
  Input Text  id=username  username
  Input Text  id=pswd   pswd
  Click Button  id=signup
```

Now, While running the test case getting an error like this -
`"Keywords select window fails"`

`Value Error : Unable to locate window with title 'Sign in - Google accounts " !`

I have also tried with URL instead of title, that also didn't work!

I have searched a lot for this issue in google, but didn't get any proper solution for this particular issue.

I hope you guys can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Well, it says what is the problem - there's no window with that title. Are you sure the string is correct? Is that really another window - but not a div or similar element/overlay in the current one? Can you give a real url so we can check? And most importantly - why am I commenting on questions 1.5 years old? :D jk on the last part, would be happy to help if you give some more details.

Comment: Have you tried:
Select Window locator=NEW Have you tried to get the window handles on the Google window with keywords like:
Get Window Names or Get Window Handles or Get Window Sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Well, use handle to switch it. Get Window Handles keyword for getting how many the browser you open. Because the Google Sign in is my second browser, then I type handles 1

```
Register with Google
Click Button    google-signin-btn-0
${handles}=  Get Window Handles
Switch Window   ${handles}[1]
Sleep    3s
```