# How to upload a csv file from local machine using robot framework script?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, robotframework, csv-file

Is there any option in robot framework to upload a csv file ( or any kind of file ) from local machine ?

Here is my testing scenario -

While clicking on  'Upload file' button a new window will pop up ( It's not part of application, it's a common windows explorer(libraries) pop up menu - [Please refer screenshot] )

[image]

then, I have to upload a csv file from my system to our web application.

But am not able to do anything after pop up window appears in screen !

Is there any option to select the windows pop up menu using the keyword 
`Select Window` or any other alternative option ?

If it's possible, then how to specify the filename in the pop up window ?

Please help me to resolve this issue !

[ *Note - I am using Selenium2Library & chrome browser* ]

Any sample test case is more helpful.

[ I came to know that , using `Choose File` keyword we can achieve the same, but I couldn't find it's sample usage anywhere and this keyword will only work with Firefox . I cann't use firefox for this testing because of the issue which I mentioned here : [Unable to handle google authentication window using firefox in robot framework](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/unable-to-handle-google-authentication-pop-up-window-in-robot-framework-test-cas) ]

Comment: Please find the answer in the below mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620136/file-upload-option-in-automation-testing-using-robot-framework

Comment: Why do you say `Choose File` only works on Firefox? I use it on chrome regularly.

Comment: I saw about this in this link -   [Choose File](http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.9#Choose%20File)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `Choose File`. You claim it only works on Firefox, but I use it on chrome regularly.

Assuming that your web page has an input element with an id of "file_input", and you have a file on disk named "/tmp/testfile.txt", you would use it like this (in pipe separated format for clarity, but you can use any format):

```
| | Choose file | id=file_input | /tmp/testfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution  ! But I would like to know one more thing.. The file explorer window will pop up when clicking on a particular button in my web application... As per your solution I have to specify the the 'id'  of the input element ! So, do I have to specify the 'id' of that particular Button ?

Comment: @ArunRamachandran: not the button. You specify the id of the `<input>` element that will get the filename. You shouldn't be clicking the button, call `Choose File` _instead_ of clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload file using the Windows explorer then you need to use [AutoIT with Selenium](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/upload-a-file-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoit), this will simulate your windows action.

You should try using the [ChooseFile](http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.9#Choose%20File) function for uploading the file directly. Refer to these link ([Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811839/uploading-a-text-file-by-clicking-a-browse-button)) for more details.

Comment: Do I have to include any other tool for uploading file using centOS file explorer ? Can I make use of AutoIT for uploading file in centOS also?